# Ember open new window avoiding pop-up blocker in a successful promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, ember.js, popup-blocker

I am struggling to find a way to open a new window inside a `then()` promise after creating a store record and persisting.

The following code is blocked by chrome's pop-up blocker

```
var obj = this.get('store').createRecord('user', {
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Smith'
});

obj.save()
  .then(function (user) {
    window.open('http://google.com', '_blank'); // this is blocked by chrome pop-up blocker
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    this.set('errors', error.errorArray); // display errors in the template
  });
```

This code works and bypasses the pop-up blocker but my problem is that if the backend throws errors during save, I don't want to open the new window since in the end the user was not successfully created and I want them to still be on the main window where they can see the error. I can close the window if I get errors but that does not feel right since it will look like a flicker of opening and closing the window immediately.

```
var window_handle = window.open('', '_blank');

var obj = this.get('store').createRecord('user', {
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Smith'
});

obj.save()
  .then(function (user) {
    window_handle.location.href = 'http://google.com'; // this is NOT blocked by chrome pop-up blocker
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    this.set('errors', error.errorArray); // display errors in the template
  });
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

`save` returns `Promise`. and It has success and error function.You can try error function instead of catch. 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_save

```
obj.save()
  .then(function (user) {
    var window_handle = window.open('', '_blank'); //if you need window_handle outside then you keep reference outside.
    window_handle.location.href = 'http://google.com'; // this is NOT blocked by chrome pop-up blocker
  },function (error) {
    this.set('errors', error.errorArray); // display errors in the template
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    this.set('errors', error.errorArray); // display errors in the template
  });
```